# Removing duplicates in a for loop crashes Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, for-loop

I have a for next loop that runs through a couple hundred thousand lines making changes on most. Could an array to make this code run faster?

The example of my for loop. Sometimes it gets overloaded and crashes Excel. (FYI my loop has to run bottom to top for it to do its intended purpose.)

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()

Dim shWorkBook As Worksheet
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim FullYearData As Worksheet
Set wkb = ThisWorkbook

With wkb
    Set shWorkBook = .Sheets("Workbook")
    Set shFullYearData = .Sheets("FullYearData")
End With

Dim i As Long
Dim LastRowW As Long

On Error Resume Next

Call TurnOffCalc

FirstRowW = shWorkBook.Cells(1, 1).Row
FirstColW = shWorkBook.Cells(1, 1).Column
LastRowW = shWorkBook.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastColW = shWorkBook.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

i = LastRowW

Sum = 0
shWorkBook.Activate

For i = LastRowW To 1 Step -1
    If shWorkBook.Cells(i, 7) = shWorkBook.Cells(i - 1, 7) Then
        shWorkBook.Cells(i, 26) = vbNullString
    End If
    
    If shWorkBook.Cells(i, 26).Value <> "" Then
        shWorkBook.Cells(i, 27) = Sum + Cells(i, 25).Value
        Sum = 0
    ElseIf shWorkBook.Cells(i, 26).Value = "" Then

        Sum = shWorkBook.Cells(i, 25).Value + Sum
    End If
Next

p = FirstRowW + 1
For p = FirstRowW + 1 To LastRowW Step 1
    shWorkBook.Cells(p, 28) = Application.WeekNum(shWorkBook.Cells(p, 3))
Next

shWorkBook.Cells(1, 28).Value = "Week Number"
Call TurnOnCalc
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Okay, you have a lot going on here so I would start by adding `Option Explicit` to the top of your module and properly declaring all your variables. What is the purpose of `FirstRowW` and `FirstColW`? These are always going to be 1. Then you go to make `p = FirstRowW + 1`, which will always be 2, then use it as an iterable on the very next line (so this is pointless). What is the point of `shFullYearData`? I don't see it used anywhere. Lastly, you need to remove `On Error Resume Next` to see if you're actually encountering an error instead of Excel just "overloading and crashing".

Comment: You need to be clear - at one point you say you want to use an array to make your code faster, but then you claim that you code doesn't work at all? Why worry about speed if your code doesn't even compile/run?

Comment: So the code does work, it just takes a very long time when running through the entire dataset so I wanted to see if there was a way to do what my for next loop was doing more efficiently.  The shFullYearData is another sheet in the workbook and I guess has no purpose being there

Comment: Why not move `shWorkBook.Cells(p, 28) = Application.WeekNum(shWorkBook.Cells(p, 3))` inside your loop that is going backwards and just use `i` instead of `p`? Unless these cells are formulas based on the results from your first loop?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()

    Dim shWorkBook As Worksheet
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim FullYearData As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, Sum
    Dim LastRowW As Long, LastColW As Long, tbl As Range, data
    
    
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    With wkb
        Set shWorkBook = .Sheets("Workbook")
        'Set shFullYearData = .Sheets("FullYearData")
    End With
    
    LastRowW = shWorkBook.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastColW = shWorkBook.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    Set tbl = shWorkBook.Range("A1").Resize(LastRowW, 28) 'include "Week number" (?)
    data = tbl.Value 'get the range value as an array
    data(1, 28) = "Week Number"

    Sum = 0
    For i = LastRowW To 1 Step -1
        
        If data(i, 7) = data(i - 1, 7) Then data(i, 26) = vbNullString
        
        If data(i, 26).Value <> "" Then
            data(i, 27) = Sum + data(i, 25).Value
            Sum = 0
        Else
            Sum = data(i, 25).Value + Sum
        End If
        
        If i > 1 Then data(i, 28) = CLng(Format(data(i, 3), "ww"))
        
    Next

    tbl.Value = data 'return the data

End Sub
```

Comment: Quick question, when using this macro one columns it is pasting includes zipcodes which sometimes have leading 0's which the array does not record (ex. zipcode 01234 will be pasted as just 1234) do you know any way I can prevent this from happening?

Comment: Are those cells formatted as text?  One way would be to make sure all values are prepended with a leading `'` (single quote)

Comment: I don't see that behavior though - anything with a leading zero still has the zero after assigning the range value to an array and then assigning the array back to the original range.